# How to pass LIST from one controller to another controller in spring mvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to select query from my database. I need to find from a list because it has many search items in the same query. So I want to get the list to do that. Select query works very well when I add `Model.addattribute`. But I don't want that. I want to do it from Ajax. So I want to pass the list to another control which is written for ajax. So please someone help me to do that.

This is my controller class which get my page

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/applicationManage")
    public String viewApplicationPage(Model model) {
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        long userId = 0;
        String agency = "";
        String units = "";
        List<String> unitsSLSI;

        if (principal != null && principal instanceof AuthenticatedUser) {
            AuthenticatedUser auth = (AuthenticatedUser) principal;
            userId = auth.getUserId();
            agency = auth.getAgency();
            unitsSLSI = auth.getJobUnits();

        }
        return "applicationManage";
    }
```

I want to pass `unitsSLSI` list to my another controller? The rest service (ajax) controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/SLSIApp", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @JsonIgnore
     public ResponseEntity<List<SLSNotification>> listAllSLSI(List<String> unitList) {
        List<SLSNotification> appbyUserID = jservice.getApplicationsByUnit(unitList);
        if (appbyUserID.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<SLSNotification>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }
        System.out.println("hibernate query " + new ResponseEntity<List<SLSNotification>>(appbyUserID, HttpStatus.OK));
        return new ResponseEntity<List<SLSNotification>>(appbyUserID, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

when I add this cord

```
  List<SLSNotification> appbyUserID = jservice.getApplicationsByUnit(unitList);
```

I want to get `unitList` from my previous controller because it has my search list. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `@JsonIgnore` as you response gets ingored...

Comment: You might also need to add @ResponseBody to that listAllSLSI.

Comment: Nope, he is returning response entity so that all he needs.

Comment: @Antoniossss ..How to this...I cantrv6 understand to do this

Comment: @Lukas Bradley..If u can please modify the cord

Comment: @NipunVidarshana you got `@JsonIgnore` above your response. Just delete it.

Comment: ah ok..I delete it..Success

Comment: @NipunVidarshana Great, now would you kindly upvode and accept answer as a form of gratitude, Thanks :)